# How to better automate a program that requires multiple programs and urls

Tags: python, awk, sed, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect some specific data from a website called 82games.com. I currently have a solution using beautifulsoup, awk and sed but it is not ideal. For starters I want the capability to iterate through multiple html pages – and run my program on all of them iteratively instead of redoing the process eg. typing in a new url and new destination.txt file for each page.

Python, BS4, awk, sed.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def function():
    page = requests.get('http://www.82games.com/1819/18ATL16.HTM#bypos')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser").text
    text = str(soup)
    print(type(text))
    print(str(cleantext))
    ans = remove(text)
    return ans

def remove(string): 
    return "".join(string.split())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function()
```

## Driver code (in bash)

> python nba_stats.py | awk NF > JohnCollinsAH2.txt
>
> sed -i '1,/Production By Postion/d' JohnCollinsAH2.txt

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It's a web spider engine that allows you to follow links and output structured data. It [integrates with BeautifulSoup](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-scrapy-with-beautifulsoup) so you'll be able to keep your parsing logic.